# Why this installation fails? (Download finished with wrong size - eclipse and android SDK manager)

Tags: android, eclipse, windows, sdk

I got these three errors. There were no network disconnections.

(Eclipse classic 4.2 win 7 ultimate x64)

Looking at those errors, would you be able to know why the installation fails?

```
Downloading ICS_R1, Android API 15, revision 3
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 117308250 bytes, got 779 bytes.

Downloading XOOM2ME, Android API 13, revision 2
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 122780710 bytes, got 779 bytes.

Downloading XOOM2, Android API 13, revision 2
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 123990783 bytes, got 779 bytes.

Downloading XOOM, Android API 11, revision 2
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 1785905 bytes, got 779 bytes.

Downloading ADMIRAL, Android API 10, revision 5
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 68883101 bytes, got 779 bytes.

Downloading ATRIX2, Android API 10, revision 2
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 73777114 bytes, got 779 bytes.

Downloading Bionic, Android API 10, revision 2
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 69035909 bytes, got 779 bytes.

Downloading defy+, Android API 10, revision 1
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 67177102 bytes, got 779 bytes.

Downloading Droid4, Android API 10, revision 2
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 81222260 bytes, got 779 bytes.

Downloading DroidRAZR, Android API 10, revision 5
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 80043807 bytes, got 779 bytes.

Downloading MotorolaPro+, Android API 10, revision 2
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 67795870 bytes, got 779 bytes.
Downloading MT870, Android API 10, revision 2
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 83816454 bytes, got 779 bytes.

Downloading MT917, Android API 10, revision 1
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 91311316 bytes, got 779 bytes.

Downloading PHOTON, Android API 10, revision 1
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 116663320 bytes, got 779 bytes.

Downloading XT882, Android API 10, revision 2
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 84944911 bytes, got 779 bytes.

Downloading XT928, Android API 10, revision 3
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 86664035 bytes, got 779 bytes.
```

Done. Nothing was installed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it means your internet connection is not fast or has datalost.

try to download directly using download managers.

1. To download platforms and apis which are from google.

open SDK Manager

Copy the first statusbar address to browser (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml or http)

1. To download other manufactories apis

SDK Manager > tools > Manage Add-on Sites

copy needed address to browser

and find your package download address.
like this

```
   <sdk:archives>
     <sdk:archive os="any">
       <sdk:size>27230698</sdk:size>
       <sdk:checksum type="sha1">2d9ca1f0034d431b7f5096d3b4dd3574ac848d46</sdk:checksum>
       <sdk:url>
         http://dl.htcdev.com/sdk/download/htc_opensense_sdk.zip ==> this is address
       </sdk:url>
     </sdk:archive>
   </sdk:archives>
```

1. **If the address was just a file name Like(android-3.0-windows.zip) replace file name with xml file of apis in addressbar Like(http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml) to (http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-3.0-windows.zip)**
2. **Make Sure the Protocol is NOT https**

download the file.

next create a folder in android installed dir (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk) and rename it to "temp". put the downloaded zip file in temp folder and try to install using SDK Manager.